# Webstorm 9 autocompletion + Node.js module + JSDoc

Tags: javascript, node.js, autocomplete, webstorm

I racked my brain with this issue for a last few days but haven't managed to find out the right way.

I'm trying to write my Node.js module in a way that Webstorm will automatically process and enable autocompletion but there is no luck.

Below is the code of module I'm working on (simple wrapper for built-in Javascript Error object):

```
/**
 * @module some-module
 */

'use strict';

var util = require('util');

var httpErrors = {
    /**
     * HTTP status code 400
     *
     * @constructor
     * @name BadRequest
     * @memberOf errors
     */
    400: { name: 'BadRequest', description: 'Invalid data was sent to the server' },

    /**
     * HTTP status code 403
     *
     * @constructor
     * @name Forbidden
     * @memberOf errors
     */
    403: { name: 'Forbidden', description: 'You\'re not allowed to perform such action' }
};

/**
 * @private
 * @constructor
 *
 * @name HttpError
 * @augments WError
 *
 * @param {Number} code
 *
 * @returns {HttpError}
 */
function HttpError (code) {
    this.statusCode = code;

    if (arguments.length < 2)
        Error.call(this, httpErrors[this.statusCode].description);
    else
        Error.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    return this;
}
util.inherits(HttpError, Error);

/**
 * @private
 * @constructor
 *
 * @name E
 *
 * @param {Number} code HTTP status code
 *
 * @returns {HttpError}
 */
function E (code) {
    return HttpError.bind(this, code);
}

/**
 * @constructor
 * @name errors
 */
var errors = {};

Object.keys(httpErrors).forEach(function (errorCode) {
    var error = httpErrors[errorCode];
    errors[error.name] = new E(+errorCode);
});

module.exports = exports = errors;
```

How it is supposed to be used:

```
var errors = require('./lib');

var err = new errors.BadRequest();

console.log(err.statusCode); // should output 400
```

The problem is that it dynamically creates `errors` object, so Webstorm doesn't 'pick up' properties for autocompletion, however, I would like to make it work using JSDoc explicitly declaring properties of `module.exports` object. The way I'm doing it doesn't work for some reason.

I'd appreciate if you'd give me some advice on how to properly use JSDoc in such cases. Thank you. :)